# C#: Socket send to another application and listen for its response and continue

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I'm trying to understand how this certain scenario would work as I've never done socket programming before. I'll try to explain it pseudo-code wise.

There is an application that is on an "application" server that will perform processes/calculations.  Data specifications will be fed to this "application" server by multiple clients.  Once processing is done it will return data back to the client.

The scenario is:
Client will have data and it will need to send to the server to perform processes/calculations. I am thinking it will be using TCPClient (not sure?) to send data to the "application" server.  "Application" server will then send results back to the client and the client code will then continue with the process.

My concern now is it must wait until the "application" server sends a response. 
So here are my questions:

1. After i do the send code can I now go to the code where it will listen for a response from the "application" server such as a do-while loop where it waits for a response before it continues?
2. i am not sure if i'm using the right terminology here but if there are multiple clients hitting the "application" server and then the client must listen for a response - can i assume that I need a process to identify which response from the "application" server is for a specific client?

I haven't written the code yet but just thinking of how to approach this scenario.

thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I recommend to read a bit on how socket programming works.

Socket programming is inherently asynchronous, so an event-driven approach could be better (yes, you can use blocking functions but they are not recommended).

I don't recommend using TCPClient nor TCPListener (and if you can stay as far as you can from NetworkStreams), using a pure Socket is not very difficult and always gives a lot better results.

So now, point by point:

1. Instead of "waiting" for a response just continue with your work and when something is received then continue the process, it also will be a lot more responsive because you will not lock your app (you can do it with blocking calls but then it involves creating a new thread per socket).
2. In your server code you need a way to identify each socket with a client, usally if you use the Async methods (ReadAsync, WriteAsync) in the SocketAsyncEventArgs you have a property named "UserToken" which is an object so you can identify from which one come the callback.

Hope it helps

Comment: NetworkStream is actually pretty useful... but generally a good answer so +1

Comment: It's useful but slow, try to send massive data with it and then compare with manually using async functions, I learned it the hard way...